# No parameter on ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a parameter called action on an ajax request this way

```
$.ajax({
          url: "index.php",
          action: 'getInfo'
        }).done(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        });
```

The request is sent on the correct url but there is no action parameter when I check with firefo developer tools

Comment: Read the docs. That's what they're for. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you should use `data`, something like :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "index.php",
  data: {action: 'getInfo'},
}).done(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use as `data: {action: 'getinfo'}`